# Are shared preferences user-specific?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

If an Android  device is registered to a different user, or a different user will log in to a multi-user version of Android (4.2?), will the preferences be shared between the users of the same device?

Comment: I didn't read your question correctly, so my answer didn't make sense. I thought you meant different devices for the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared preference is user-specific. Whenever your app saves user preferences, creates a database, or writes a file to the user’s internal or external storage space, that data is accessible only while running as that user.

For further information have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Answer (score -2):

Shared perferences will not share between other users, every device as different SharedPreferences, they are used for some device high score, or some device bought items from application.